# Windows 7 x64 Enterprise after 10 min session block Windows explorer windows closes

Tags: windows-7, windows

We are having an unwanted and unexpected behavior in Windows 7 X64 Enterprise.

Whenever we leave a PC idling for more than 10 Min it blocks and activates the selected screen saver. That's ok and expected.

The thing is that when you open your blocked session typing your credentials and come back to your desktop, whatever explorer windows you had open before are now closed.

Is there a way to correct this behavior.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: anything in the event log?

Comment: Nope nothing in the even log shows any trace of this behavior

Comment: Is it possible that this behavior is because of a security update?